# How to add File to Array (List) :Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, unhandled-exception

**How to add File to Array (List)**

I got an image from ImagePicker

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
```

_images are declared by followed

```
 List<File> _images = List<File>();
```

I tried as Follows

```
_images = image as List<File>
```

But I got errors like this

> Unhandled Exception: type '_File' is not a subtype of type
> 'List' in type cast

Comment: imagepicker.pickimage flutter deprecated.

Comment: show the whole code. that would be helpful to us

Comment: `_images.add(image);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because `Future<File> pickImage(..)` returns `File` not `List<File>`.

In you code you're trying to cast `File` as `List<File>`:

```
_images = image as List<File>
```

If you only want to store the `File` returned from `Future<File>pickImage(..)`, then you can add the `File` to the `List`

```
_images.add(image);
```

Also `Future<File>pickedImage(..)` method is deprecated so please try using `Future<PickedFile> getImage(..)`, which returns `PickedFile` instead of `File`.